# filter result of mysql by numerical

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to filter the result of first character by any numerical(0-9)

in filtering by letters i use this code

```
$letter="A";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE LEFT(`title`, 1)='$letter' order by title ASC  LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
```

if i tried to change the value of variable `$letter` to `'0'` it only returns all the results character starting 0..if possible i would like to get all the numerical value

my goal was to create a navigator filtering them all by letter and number like this one
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>[`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)</kbd>

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE title REGEXP '^[0-9]'
ORDER BY title ASC;
```

**Explanation:**

`^` means start with

`[0-9]` characters (`0 or 1 or 2....to 9`) inside this subscripts

Comment: No problem mate. You can gather some knowledge on `REGEXP in MySQL`. Added a reference in the answer.

Comment: thanks I've been brainstorming and looking for some same question here within an hour haha thanks a lot